# Reading nested dictionary-like txt file into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

Sort of a new python guy here and haven't had much success with the following.

I have a txt file with data formatted as follows:

```
{
  "$type" : "TableInstance",
  "$version" : 1,
  "Instance" : "InstanceName",
  "ColumnAliases" : [ "", "", ],
  "ColumnNames" : [ "keyName", "dateName"],
  "ColumnData" : [ {
    "type" : "ColumnData1",
    "Strings" : [key1, key2],]
  }, {
    "type" : "ColumnData2",
    "Strings" : [date1, date2]}]
}
```

That I would like to read into a dataframe such that it is formatted as:

```
[   keyName     dateName
    key1        date1
    key2        date1 ]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: Are you sure there is not an error in the text? It is almost plain python dictionary syntax, if it was you could just read it in and use exec(). There are some inconsistent "[" and "]" pairs that interleave with "{" and "}" pairs, it is a bit of a mess, are you sure it is right?.. If this really IS what you need to parse then I think you'll be forced to write a parser. I can recommend the "parsimonious" package, it makes it pretty easy.

Comment: You are right -- I took a sample of some of the text file and changed some of the names before I posted here, so I mixed up the [] and {} positions. I'm not familiar with exec -- will look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
dict = {
  "$type" : "TableInstance",
  "$version" : 1,
  "Instance" : "InstanceName",
  "ColumnAliases" : [ "", "", ],
  "ColumnNames" : [ "keyName", "dateName"],
  "ColumnData" : [ {
    "type" : "ColumnData1",
    "Strings" : ['key1', 'key2']
  }, {
    "type" : "ColumnData2",
    "Strings" : ['date1', 'date2']}]
}

df = pd.DataFrame({dict['ColumnNames'][0]:dict['ColumnData'][0]['Strings'], dict['ColumnNames'][1]:dict['ColumnData'][1]['Strings']})
```

Comment: It is actually a much, much larger text file than what I provided, which was just a sample. So reading it into a dictionary to begin with is proving tricky...

Comment: @agold2121 in that case you're probably not getting out of writing a parser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it that you stored the serialized python object in the file. Hence, you can deserialize the Python object by the help of pickle, then you can parse the object based on your requirements.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

filePath = 'test.txt'
obj = pd.read_pickle(filePath)
#obj = pickle.load(open(filePath, "rb"))
df = pd.DataFrame({obj['ColumnNames'][0]:obj['ColumnData'][0]['Strings'], obj['ColumnNames'][1]:obj['ColumnData'][1]['Strings']})
```